# R dplyr error using as.POSIXct to filter date data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate, posixct

**strong text**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- na.omit(read.csv('...'))
df1
all_cities <- unique(df1$City)
pt1_cities <- all_cities[1:25]
pt2_cities <- all_cities[26:50]
pt3_cities <- all_cities[51:75]
pt4_cities <- all_cities[76:100]

library(ggplot2)
df1 %>% mutate(When = as.POSIXct(dt, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% filter(When >= as.Date("1860-01-01")) %>%
  filter(City == all_cities[3]|City == all_cities[6]|City == all_cities[9]) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(When,AverageTemperature,color = as.factor(City)) + geom_point()
```

At last 4lines of code, when I run it, program returns
">="�� ȣȯ�Ǵ� �޼ҵ���� �ƴմϴ� ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date")

How can I remove that error??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you provide a reproducible example? A sample of the data you are using would help people a lot in understanding the problem.

Comment: They say I can post image after 10 reputations so I have to explain as words. Sorry for that. "dt(1849-01-01)  AverageTemperature(26.704) City(Abidjan) Country(~~) Latitude(~~) Longitude(~~)" These datas are in excel file, and I wanted to filter data by dt but it was fctr type data so I tried to change it to date type data.

Comment: Are you sure that all values in your excel-generated file are valid? For example, can you try to check for rows where `When` is not properly parsed? `df1 %>% mutate(When = as.POSIXct(dt, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% filter(is.na(When), !is.na(dt))`